# How to tuning is not null to range scan index in Oracle explain plan?

Tags: oracle, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I m building a search query right now. I used the Oracle 19c database.

sample query:

```
select * from t1 
inner join t2 on t2.id = t1.id and t2.name <> 'AKA'
left outer join t3 Buyer on Buyer.id = t1.id and Buyer.userId is null
left outer join t3 Seller on Seller.id = t1.id and Seller.userId = t1.userId
where rownum < 500;
```

This query runs super slow without indexes. It took like 14s to feed the result.
I checked the explain plan and give some indexes to the database. The query time down to 3s! Yeah. BUT,BUT,BUTBBBBBUT. It's not enough. I need it to react even faster like 1s.

I rechecked the autotrace. There still two place use full scan event I gave them the index.

**The first is**

```
 INDEX       t2.name
                                                                
     - Filter Predicates 
                                                                                
           - t2.NAME<>'AKA'
```

Is there a way to do <> index in Oracle? I tried build index in multiple ways. For example,
`create index t2_name_idx on t2 (case when name <> 'AKA' then name end);`, not work. Also the sample way like `create index t2_name_idx on t2 (name);` not works too.

**The second is**

```
HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER    890639      556473      400400      2906406 
 Access Predicates 
 AND 
 T3.ID=T1.ID 
 T3.USERID=T1.USERID                                            
 TABLE ACCESS 
 ADDRESSES   BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED      1225069     314696      384117      596570 
                                                        
 INDEX 
 T3_UERID    FULL SCAN   1225069     4708    4678    121216 
                                                                
 Filter Predicates
                                                                        
 T3.USERID IS NOT NULL
```

Above means that when doing `left outer join t3 Seller on Seller.id = t1.id and Seller.userId = t1.userId` it will check the t3.userid is not null first. The index T3_USERID is just a simple non-unique index on table T3 col T3.userid.

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Using `<>` or `!=` generally prevents the use of any index.

Comment: @pmdba Right, but I am thinking about a way like create a index like:

t2 (t2.name > 'AKA', T2.NAME < 'AKA').